# InputField with a symbol’s name

Tags: string-manipulation, symbols

Suppose I have an InputField of type String wherein I want to enter a symbol name that I want a later Button to assign values to. That button would then do something like:

```
Evaluate[ToSymbol[string]]=stuff
```

But if the symbol name that is entered already has been assigned a value, this fails because the left-hand-side becomes the value, to which it is not valid to assign a new value. How do I convert the string to a symbol without evaluating that symbol?

Comment: I think your question is fully answered in the linked topic but let me know if you disagree with marking it a duplicate.

Comment: Agreed. Thank you for pointing me to that linked topic. I am not sure why my searches didn't pull that one up...

Comment: No worries, it is really tough to find a duplicate unless you know the answer or have seen it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `ToExpression` with its three arguments form and construct the `Set` programmatically:

```
   varname="test";
   value=RandomReal[];
   Set @@ Append[ToExpression[varname, InputForm, Hold], value]
```

Can you explain why you want to do this? I see many potential problems when you allow users of your gui to do this, they could e.g. accidentially overwrite any of the symbols you have defined in your code...

Comment: It is a large, multi-tabbed interface that will be part of a `Package`. It focuses on nonlinear fitting of experimental data to differential rate equations. I need the user, when the fit is done, to be able to output the results to their own variable. I also need the user to be able to output the state of a bunch of internal variables so that they can reuse the model set parameters when fitting at a later date. Overwriting symbols in my code is not a concern because nearly all of those symbols are local, and I will be adding a way to ensure that the symbol name input is global.